# Convert date to Wyy(week number) Format

Tags: excel

I am working with Excel 2010.
I wish to convert (for example) cell A1 with today's date in the format 4/10/2017 to a format which is W1715 (W(last two digits of year)(weeknumber)).
It would be great if anyone could help!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A1 has the Date and is formatted as Date (Excel recognize it as Date) just write in B1 where you want the result:
`="W"&VALUE(RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2))&WEEKNUM(A1,1)`
Right(Year(A1),2) returns the last 2 digits of the four digit of the Year
Weeknum returns the number of the week 1 correspond at 1st week is the week which has the 1st of January week begins on Sunday

Comment: @Pooja Be sure you understand the different `return_type`s for `WEEKNUM` so as to return the correct one for your needs.  There is also an `ISOWEEKNUM` function (not present in 2010) which counts as Week1 the first week that has four or more days in the year (eg contains Jan 4), and is different from MS's `WEEKNUM` function.  If you need that, then you might need a UDF or more complicated formula

Comment: @Pooja Kindly if you are satisfied with the answer accept  it

Comment: @RonRosenfeld In Excel 2010 you can get `ISO` week numbers by using `WEEKNUM` with return type `21`

Comment: @barryhoudini  Good to know.  I went from 2007 ► 2016, so wasn't sure when all the changes were made.  And, contrary to the current HELP topic, I don't recall options other than 1 or 2 for WEEKNUM in 2007.